# Create a Flip Card Animation with React Native

Tags: react-native

I try Create a Flip Card Animation with React Native with link here. but I  getting mirrored text of back text on flipping.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB4tC.jpg

[Code Create a Flip Card Animation with React Native][1]

https://github.com/browniefed/examples/blob/animated_basic/flip/animatedbasic/index.android.js

Comment: I think because use 'backfaceVisibility' on android, try this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1973#issuecomment-262059217

Comment: thanks!!! @PTT . I fixed a problem.